# Need help to deserialize XML data

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize the below XML using C#

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Invoice>
 <Samples>
 <Sample>
   <AccountId>1e547ae6-9a6d-d18f-958b-22000b83a845</AccountId>
   <AccountNumber>55761598808</AccountNumber>
 </Sample>
 <Sample>
  <AccountId>1e547ae6-9a6d-d18f-958b-22000b83a845</AccountId>
  <AccountNumber>55761598808</AccountNumber>
 </Sample>
 </Samples>
</Invoice>
```

Here are the classes that I have defined to deserialize

```
         [DataContract(Name = "Sample")]
         public class Sample
         {
             [DataMember(Name = "AccountId")]
             public string AccountId { get; set; }
             [DataMember(Name = "AccountNumber")]
             public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
         }

         [DataContract(Name = "Samples")]
         public class Samples
         {
             [DataMember(Name = "Sample")]
             public List<Sample> Sample { get; set; }
         }

         [DataContract(Name = "Invoice")]
         public class Invoice
         {
             [DataMember(Name = "Samples")]
             public Samples Samples { get; set; }
         }
```

The corresponding test case to deserialize is as follows

```
  public void SampleXmlTest()
    {
        dynamic env = SUT.GetEnvironment();

       string dbConnStrUrjanet = (string)env.AvidUtility.UrjanetDB;
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CommonAvidXmlDto.Invoice));

        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\SJuluru\Desktop\Sample XML\Samplexml.xml");

        Object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);

        CommonAvidXmlDto.Invoice XmlData4 = (CommonAvidXmlDto.Invoice)obj;
```

After running the test case debug mode, XmlData4 has null without having the XML data. Kindly help me how to modify this code to work.

Answer (score 0):

`DataContract` and `DataMember` are attribute of `DataContractSerializer` so you shoud replace your serializer [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or use `XmlSerializer`'s attributes (`XmlRoot, XmlElement` etc)

Answer (score 0):

**Change deserialize classes:**

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Sample")]
    public class Sample
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "AccountId")]
        public string AccountId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "AccountNumber")]
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Samples")]
    public class Samples
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Sample")]
        public List<Sample> Sample { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Invoice")]
    public class Invoice
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Samples")]
        public Samples Samples { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Use below method for deserialize:**

```
private static Invoice LoadInvoice(string fileName)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Invoice));

    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        return null;
    }
    using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        return (Invoice)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]